# Could not load file or assembly - dll from class library is not copied over to asp.net project bin folder

Tags: c#, .net, reference, runtime-error

I added new nuget packages to a class library that is a project reference to an asp.net wep api project (4.6.2 version).
When I start the api project an exception is thrown and I see this error message naming the packages I added.

- Could not load file or assembly

I used the [Fusion Log Viewer](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/fusion-log-viewer-fuslogvw-exe/ba-p/784396) to see logs for binding failures. I was able to see more log information of what was happening but nothing to point me to a solution.  I also used this tool which made it easier to view the log file [Fusion++](https://github.com/awaescher/Fusion/releases).
I tried different package versions, changing the copy local property for the specific reference from true to false and then back to true and cleaning bin folders. No luck!  The .dll for the packages I added are in the class library bin folder but not in the bin folder of the web api project. The other .dll files are there for other references, just not the new ones I added.  Some process is copying the dll files over to the other project, except the new ones I added.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by finding references to the dlls that had been copied to the other project inside the properties view of the project where the packages had been installed. There were Post-Build Events using xcopy to copy the files to the api project.  For reference this post explains what I found and what I had to do to get the dlls copied over.  [Post-Build Events and xcopy](https://jeremybytes.blogspot.com/2014/02/using-build-events-in-visual-studio-to.html)